# Diagnostics.Process doesn't open PDF file using adobe reader

Tags: c#, pdf, process.start, adobe-reader

I'm having a problem while trying to open a PDF file using Process.Start().
The program runs the process as a background process but no adobe reader window show up. A solution i found was to use chrome.exe, but my client want to open on adobe-reader, as it's the default windows program.

(I have also trying without forcing "AcroRd32.exe" and passing the full path of "AcroRd32.exe". Same problem).

Anyone solved this?

*My code:*

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"AcroRd32.exe", @"D:\Tests\81803130000326__.pdf")
};
p.Start();
```

*Background Processes:*

[image: Background Process image]

I also have checked this question: [Process.Start(/* path to pdf */) doesn't work with Adobe Reader on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778366/process-start-path-to-pdf-doesnt-work-with-adobe-reader-on-windows-8)

## **Edits**

**EDIT INFO**: Forgot to say i'm running Windows 10 with Adobe Reader DC 2018.009.20044

**EDIT 2**: Found a "problem" of Adobe Reader DC. It mantains a level of security that doesn't let me run it as administrator (don't ask me why). Check this link for more information: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1955530

Now I'll try to find a solution to run it without administrator privileges, or ask my client to uncheck the checkbox

## **Solution**

So, I've found a solution for my problem. The Adobe Reader, since version 10.0, has a "Protected Mode" setting. I wrote a code to change that setting in the registry, so the user won't need to do that. Link: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/protectedmode.html

I hope it helps others in the future!

**Solution Code**:

```
var registroAdobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\", true);
registroAdobe.SetValue("bProtectedMode", 0);
```

This works for Acrobat Reader DC. You can run through "Software\Policies\Adobe\" Products and Versions if you need it.

Comment: Try passing in the full path to AcroRd32.exe.

Comment: I open direct the pdf file, `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("output.pdf");`, this use the default pdf viewer that you have installed in your computer.

Comment: @Botonomous Like i said, i got the same problem :(

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas Same thing occours. All these works the same way. The system\program understants and open the process, but doesn't open the adobe reader window

Comment: What's your default program to open pdf files?

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas Adobe Reader DC 2018.009.20044 (updated that now)

Comment: @Wesley, pass the full path to AcroRd32.exe, like this ` StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe", @"D:\temp\demonstrativo.pdf")`

Comment: Does your program run as a  Windows Service, or otherwise on Session 0 (e.g. Windows Task Scheduler)? Then you can't trivially start applications in the session of the current user. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627404/how-can-i-have-a-service-run-a-process-under-the-current-users-session

Comment: Doesn't work, @PabloTondolodeVargas :( thanks!
CodeCaster I'm trying using a new console application for that. The code is literally just that.

Discovered the problem on adobe forums. The problem is really Adobe Reader DC. Check my new EDIT

Comment: Solution Found! thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found that this didn't work on my computer, but it led me to look deeper.
I found my solution to be:

```
var regAdobe = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\Privileged", true);
regAdobe.SetValue("bProtectedMode", 0);
```

Very similar, but ended up having to edit the user setting rather than the local machine's setting.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("") to open with default pdfreader program on respective client system.